# How to create a special query with doctrine?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to resolve my problem since two days but I my code fails... Do you know how I can conert my sql query in doctrine ?

Sql query (the query work fine in phpmyadmin) :

```
SELECT distinct ms.ytId, ms.title FROM(

SELECT l.log_yt_id AS ytId, d.download_title AS title

FROM t_log l LEFT JOIN t_download d ON d.download_yt_id = l.log_yt_id WHERE l.log_creator = 'n' ORDER BY l.log_id  DESC LIMIT 100

    ) ms
```

Thanks you all for your help !!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use doctrine dql.

First:

Check this page:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Then remember:

If you want to use mysql functions like "RAND" etc. you have to define them in your config file after install a doctrine extensions bundle.